# gRPC communication between protos

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

If I define two proto files

**protoA**

```
service ServA {

    rpc request(MyMessage) returns(ResponseMessage);

}
message MyMessage{
  string body= 1;
}

message ResponseMessage{
  string body= 1;
}
```

**protoB**

```
service ServB {

    rpc request(MyMessage) returns(ResponseMessage);

    rpc newFeatures(Bla) returns(Foo)

}
message MyMessage{
  string body= 1;
}

message ResponseMessage{
  string body= 1;
}
```

Using the stub from **protoA** can  I call **protoB**

```
    this.stub = ProtoA.newBlockingStub(this.managedChannel);
    stub.request(new MyMessage("hello world")
```

I need to do this, because I have to create a new service (protoB) that has new functionality and also need to be retro compatible with the old call to **protoA**. And extend **protoA** is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this. The fully qualified name of the method, including the package and service names, determines the URL that gRPC will use to make the request. So `ServA/request` and `ServB/request` will request different URLs, and one cannot be used in place of the other.

Of course, if the services have the same name, then they can be used interchangeably, but I would describe that as extending the service, which the question says is not an option.